# Can we know at runtime if the code is running in a browser or on a server?

Tags: dart

Can we know at runtime if the code is running in a browser or on a server ?

By browser, I mean GUI, either javascript generated by dart2js or dartium.
By server, I mean CLI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655084/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-script-is-running-in-the-dart-vm-or-dart2js

Comment: This is not the same question. That question assumes we're in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pub package has been made for this case : [is_client](https://github.com/hyamamoto/is_client.dart)

you can look the code to help you if you don't want to use the package.